# Custom format for Sprout SEO 3 Element Metadata

Tags: plugin-sproutseo, plugin-neo

Does Sprout SEO work with Neo fields?

I'm trying to create multiple fallbacks within a custom formatted element metadata field in Sprout, so I could just use one Sprout SEO field with element metadata for multiple significantly different sections.

For instance, something like this:

```
{% if object.comparisonPageBodyText %}{{ object.comparisonPageBodyText | striptags }}{% else %}{{ object.body | striptags }}{% endif %}
```

I tried this, and it doesn't appear to work with Neo fields.

Ideally, my ultimate thing would be something like:

- If comparisonPageBodyText exists, use the first 160 characters
- else use the first 160 characters of the first body matrix block
- else use the section default
- else use the site default

It would be amazing if we could structure the logic inside the gui instead of writing twig, but ultimately this would be fine if I could get it to work.